# Passando dados por Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou tentando passar alguns dados via Jquery para uma outra página php.

Faço a criação da `tag < a >` via `echo`:

```
echo "<a id='".$feed_id."' class='like'> Teste LINK </a>";
```

• A variável $feed_id deve retornar um ID numérico (ex: 1234)

Tenho a função:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#like").click(function(){
                var url = "like.php";

                var data = $("#like").attr("id");

                $.post(url,{postdata:data},
                function(result) {
                    $("#result").html(result); // Só pra verificar retorno
                });

            });
```

E tento pegar o valor da variável na página like.php:

```
    $data = $_POST['postdata'];

    echo $data;
```

Preciso de algumas dicas para fazer esse código funcionar, e se possível, melhorá-lo.

Comment: E qual o problema?

Answer (score 3):

Vitor, seguem algumas observações sobre seu código.

**Atributo ID**

No trecho abaixo você define atributo ID do link com um valor numérico. Porém, não é uma boa prática definir o valor do atributo ID como apenas número, o ideal é defini-lo conforme as práticas para definição de nomes de variáveis mais comuns: O nome de uma variável deve iniciar com uma letra ou com "_" (underline).

```
echo "<a id='".$feed_id."' class='like'> Teste LINK </a>";
```

Sugiro:

```
echo "<a id='like".$feed_id."' class='like'> Teste LINK </a>";
```

**Seletor #like**

Já no trecho que segue, você utiliza o seletor **#like**, este seletor entende que o id do seu elemento é *like*, enquanto, na verdade, *like* é a classe CSS do elemento. Então o seletor correto seria **.like**.

```
$("#like").click(function(){ ...
```

Sugiro:

```
$(".like").click(function(){ ...
```

**Obter o ID do elemento clicado**

Dentro do evento *click* você faz a seguinte atribuição:

```
var data = $("#like").attr("id");
```

Entendo que a intenção `$("#like").attr("id")` é capturar o ID elemento que foi *clicado*.

Sugiro (Caso tenha atendido a sugestão referente ao atributo ID):

```
$this = $(this); // jQuery

var data = /^like(\d+)$/.exec($this.attr("id"))[1];
```

Senão:

```
$this = $(this); // jQuery

var data = $this.attr("id");
```

Comment: Boa resposta! `+1` em relação a "Obter o ID do elemento clicado" acho que `this.id` serve pois dentro do event handler o `this` já será o elemento. Só uma sugestão, vou apagar quando tiveres lido.